# Unexpected margin

Tags: margins

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\fbox {%
  \vbox to 4cm{\hbox to 4cm{\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{4cm}
    Test 1
    \end{minipage}
  }}}
  \vbox to 4cm{\hbox to 15cm{\hfill \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{6cm}
    Test 2
    \end{minipage}
  }}}
}
\end{document}
```

Which generates the following output:

[image]

My question is: where does the red-highlighted margin come from, and how can I set it?

I'm pretty new to LaTeX, it's highly possible that I'm missing something obvious, do not hesitate to redirect me to an appropriate doc!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Looks like the paragraph indentation ...

Comment: Try `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`, but your boxes are too large any way, as they reach into the right margin (and the box generation looks a little, say, strange)

Comment: you are also missing a `%` after `\end{minipage}` (twice)

Comment: You're missing a `\noindent` instruction ahead of `\fbox`.

Comment: and `\vbox to 4cm{` is not a latex command it's a tex primitive that should not be used within the document. use teh optional height argument of `minipage` if ypu want to force a certain height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the desired layout, then

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][4cm]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
\framebox[4cm][l]{Test 1}\hfill
\framebox[6cm][l]{Test 2}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```